# Not able to click on a javascript link using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on a javascript link using webdriver.

Below is the **HTML** code:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenWindow(&quot;rsm7&quot;,&quot;CHG:Change Management Console&quot;,1,0);"> Change Management Console</a>
```

Below is my **webdriver** code:

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("username-id")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("username-id")).sendKeys("shruthi");
driver.findElement(By.id("pwd-id")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("pwd-id")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Change Management Console")).click();
```

I am getting `NoSuchElementException`. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below line

```
 driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Change Management Console")).click();
```

Try this line

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'Change Management Console')]")).click();
```